# Materialize not being included when running main-bower-files gulp task

Tags: gulp, bower, materialize

I have recently installed materialize in my project using bower, and I have a main-bower-files task to concatenate the js files across my bower components into a distribution location.

I am finding that materialize is not getting included after the task is run and I cannot find any references to materialize in the final concatenated file.

Materialize does appear in my project's bower_components folder and I can see the JS sources present.

I also have a separate task for concatenating the css files across my bower components, and I do actually see the materialize css being added.

So for some reason the JS side of things is not being included.

Can anyone help me in figuring out why this could be please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, kept searching for 1 hour, with no results for the problem but this post!

I fixed the problem by overriding what to import like:

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
return gulp.src('./bower.json')
    .pipe(mainBowerFiles({
      overrides: {
        Materialize: {
          main: [
            './dist/*/*.min.*',
          ]
        }
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/libs'));
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem